# Failing to build PostGIS on OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: postgis, osx

I am trying to install postGIS from source to match the default install of postgreSQL on OS X 10.7. I installed GEOS and PORJ.4 from Kyngchaos and ran

```
$export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7
$export CFLAGS="-Os -arch i386 -arch x86_64" 
$export PG_CPPFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
$export SHLIB_LINK="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
$export LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
$cd ~/source/postgis
postgis $./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/bin/pg_config --with-geosconfig=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config --with-projdir=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Unix
```

I get this

```
PostGIS is now configured for x86_64-apple-darwin11.0.0
```

however after running make i get the following error

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/dh/11gwx5cs5sl8v4r7qrzf3pd00000gn/T//ccsAdaB9.out (No such file or directory)
make[1]: *** [postgis-1.5.so] Error 1
make: *** [postgis] Error 2
```

Something i don't know about (architecture?) seems wrong here. Any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` means that some error occurred earlier in the log. To really have a chance at debugging this, someone would need the __full__ log---everything from the time you ran `./configure`. You could post it in a pastebin like [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com).

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem, but with Snow Leopard. Did you solve them? These 2 links talk about the same, but don't provide a confirmed solution http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2011-September/030665.html http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2011-September/030666.html

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess and say that you need to pass `--disable-dependency-tracking` as an argument to `./configure`. Usually Configure will set up Makefiles so that "dependency tracking" information is gathered by invoking GCC using `-M*` flags. These flags cannot be used when multiple `--arch` flags are passed to generate fat binaries.

Just a guess---can't say for sure without the full logs for `configure` and `make`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this post: [Installing PostgreSQL and PostGIS on Mac OS X](http://lassebunk.dk/2011/09/08/installing-postgresql-and-postgis-on-mac-os-x/) (for Lion)

Answer (score -1):

**A quick workaround** on Lion is to move `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in `/etc/paths`, then logout and log back in.

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6343

Comment: I don't think this will solve his problem. He is already supplying `configure` with an explicit path to `pg_config` and states that he wants to "match the default install of postgreSQL on OS X 10.7"---i.e. the one installed in `/usr` and certainly not anything in `/usr/local`.