# Failing to build PostGIS on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: postgis, osx

I'm getting the same problem expressed here

[Failing to build PostGIS on OS X 10.7 Lion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13591/failing-to-build-postgis-on-os-x-10-7-lion/21471)

But in Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Things I have checked include:

- PostgreSQL compiled to several architectures. I used the binary from http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/, and tested the dynlib objects with the tool file
- PROJ and GEOS compiled for i386 and x86_64. I used the frameworks from http://www.kyngchaos.com
- GDAL compiled from sources following KyngChaos instructions. I compiled it instead of using the provided framework because I'm a GDAL developer, and I'm going to work with it.
- Trying to compile PostGIS, because I'm a PostGIS developer too, and I don't want to use the binaries. It has been configured correctly. I used this: https://gist.github.com/2002495

But I'm still getting the error: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`

Other things I've tried:

- Compile ONLY for arch i386. Not working. PostgreSQL expects PostGIS compiled for both architectures. I get the error ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64.
- Compile ONLY for arch x86_64. Not working, for the same reason. I get the error ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

I could provide configure and makefile logs, if needed, but the problem is this. It's a problem known in PostGIS lists, but I still haven't found a solution...

Thanks in advance, and best regards

Comment: Maybe you should add a link to the problem as expressed on the PostGIS mailing lists ...

Comment: I solved the problem, but here the link to my message in the postgis-devel list: http://postgis.refractions.net/pipermail/postgis-devel/2012-March/019497.html

Comment: Do you really need PostGIS as a fat binary? If it is just for use on one Mac (i.e. you are not distributing binaries to other machines), save yourself a dumptruckload of pain and just build everything as x86_64. A package manager such a Homebrew or MacPorts can also help get things installed.

Comment: Yes, it's only for me. I could compile only for x86_64. I'm probably too lazy, because I followed instructions that compile for both archs. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build for both and only exclude powerpc binaries.

```
 ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" ./configure
 ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" ./make
```

But honestly, if you are already in the Kyngchaos realm with GEOS and proj.4, then just grab his [PostgreSQL/PostGIS binaries](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres), too.

Comment: Thanks for  the tip. Now I'm getting a different error:

ar: libpgcommon.a is a fat file (use libtool(1) or lipo(1) and ar(1) on it)
ar: libpgcommon.a: Inappropriate file type or format.

I'd use the binaries, but the point is I'm a GDAL/PostGIS developer, and I need to compile both libraries by myself.

Comment: I finally solved the problem compiling PostgreSQL using -arch i386 -arch x86_64.

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably misunderstanding your answer, but your suggestion was to compile PostGIS with those flags. My solution was to compile PostgreSQL, a prerequisite, using those flags too, instead of using a precompiled version of PostgreSQL. Anyway, I'll mark your answer as valid.

Comment: Any binary that you will link against must match the architecture. So in your case client-postgresql/proj/geos/gdal/postgis/etc must match. When in doubt, use the **file <library_name>** command.

Comment: Yes, I discovered the "file" command, and it's really useful. Thanks for the tip!